# Link to code of conduct broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, 404-not-found, code-of-conduct

The [recent blog post "Get to Know Our New Code of Conduct"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/08/07/get-to-know-our-new-code-of-conduct/) contains a link to the new code of conduct,  https://stackoverflow.com/conduct. As of `2018-08-07T05:27:38+00`, [that link returns a 404](https://web.archive.org/web/20180807051015/https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). Also, I cannot find any other link to the conduct yet, neither in the help center, nor in the site navigation, which is a bummer, given that we're invited to read the new CoC:

> Really, please, take a moment to read the new Code of Conduct now. It’s not long, it’s not wordy-and-legalese-y and in our long held tradition, we feel that it does a good job of assuming that the vast majority of folks that use our sites always have the best intentions at heart.

Is the code of conduct not yet published?

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, https://dev.stackoverflow.com/ announces the conduct and links to https://dev.stackoverflow.com/conduct, so maybe it's not public yet?

Comment: I _guess_ that the `/conduct` isn't public yet, but already viewable for higher ups. That's only speculation, though.

Comment: I don't believe that the link is wrong, because before the blog post went out I happened to visit [Stack Overflow's development server](https://dev.stackoverflow.com) and there was a clear link to it in a banner.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog adds to my guess: it's not yet on the public servers. I'll keep the title, though, since it's currently broken for the public. But good to know that the link itself _will_ be correct.

Comment: Come to think of it, why isn't there a link to the main CoC from within the help pages or at the bottom of the main site?  Why are people forced to go to the blog to follow a link to read the whole thing?

Comment: @Snow that was part of [the first revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/313694/1). I _guess_ that the `dev.stackoverflow.com` server contains a link in its help center. Maybe someone with `dev.*` access can confirm that?

Comment: @Zeta So it is.  I think I fell into the standard trick of only reading the first sentence, feeling angst, and then going directly to the quote block.  But then I don't think the first version of the CoC was easily discoverable either, so restating the blindingly obvious seems appropriate here.

Comment: Moderator points user to code of conduct, user says "Where is it?", moderator says "Well, you need to go find this blog entry then click on a link...".  Any other community website, there's an easily discoverable CoC.  But not here.

Comment: @Snow And then they click on the link in the blog, and get a 404.

Comment: Meh, that CoC is just a late April 1 joke.

Comment: @rene "higher up" as in "has access on `dev.stackoverflow.com`". I don't have access, and I have no idea who has, as it is "invite only"(?) (: (see comments 2,3,5)

Comment: Maybe they didn't publish a Code of Conduct, but a Clash of Clans?

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ It's definitely a Circle of Confusion by now.

Comment: As of `2018-08-07T13:26:50+00:00`, the blog post is down. It's still in the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20180807050603/https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/08/07/get-to-know-our-new-code-of-conduct/. The probable answer is that the blog post was a little bit too early and I was a little bit too eager to read the new CoC :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There was an error scheduling the blog post. Somehow (we're looking into it), the time zone that the post scheduler used was flipped, so what was supposed to go out at 1PM EDT actually went out much sooner.

We've un-published the post until the actual routes go live, at which time the post scheduler (should) simply publish it at 1:00 PM today (EDT), which was chosen because it gives everyone involved ample time to make sure everything actually, you know, works.

We have yet to identify the actual culprit, but *one* employee has reported feeding a strange furry pet past midnight *after* getting it wet, so we're chasing that lead with a bit of optimism.

Comment: That's right, blame the new guy....  :D

Comment: Was it necessary to get the pet wet?

Comment: @AnneDaunted For reproduction, yes. But we have no details regarding if the pet was or wasn't on fire at the time. We hope to have more information soon, and we'll keep everyone updated.

Comment: Oh, you reproduce the pets? When can we get our SO gremlin, and how much will they cost?

Comment: Someone isn't [afraid enough of timezones](https://xkcd.com/1883/) yet

Comment: it was an unicorn, for sure...and that new guy was asking to parse HTML with RegEx