# Please don't hide the Code of Conduct in a Blog entry

Tags: feature-request, code-of-conduct

We all know that currently, the newly released [Code of Conduct is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313694/link-to-code-of-conduct-broken) blog page was erroneously published early.

However, as part of the linked question, Zeta points out that the CoC has no discovery points within the general UI of the site as a whole.  I believe this has always been the case.

Yes, I know that snippets of the CoC are contained within the help pages, but the document as a whole isn't.

If we refer users to the Code of Conduct, we're forced to point them toward help pages that don't explicitly mention that they're part of the CoC, and for a lot of people, "help" just means "guidance" and is therefore optional.

Right now, if we direct people to the site-wide Code of Conduct, we have to direct them to a blog site, and then to find the link within it.  We can give them the direct link, but that doesn't help them to understand how they should have been able to find it in the first place.

A Code of Conduct is great, but users should be able to find it easily and under their own steam - that way, they can't use ignorance as an excuse.

When the link is fixed, please consider making the CoC easily discoverable.  Either by clearly linking to it in the help pages, or put a link to it at the bottom of the page.

You've done great work in making the CoC easier for people to understand.  Please also make it easier to access.

Comment: The code of conduct doesn't yet exist. Currently, it doesn't make much sense having a bunch of broken links in the software. But when it goes live, they should definitely be added.

Comment: Obviously, I'm not asking for broken links to be added... To be fair, the Blog shouldn't have gone live with a broken link in the first place.

Comment: Just speculating on the reason why the team decided not to link it from the system yet. It looks like they accidentally published the post.

Comment: The developer page https://dev.stackoverflow.com/ announces the CoC, so at least the _initial_ variant will be visible. But I concur with the rest, it should be always easy to find.

Comment: I agree with this as to find the current CoC you have to go into help and realize that under our model the [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) heading is actually a code of conduct. So I hope they don't only over-write this page but make it easier to understand this is our code of conduct.

Answer (score 2):

Ok.

Link to the real Code of Conduct is right there front and center in the help screen.  I'm happy with that.  Easy to find and almost unavoidable.

Thanks!